# Minimax Tic Tac Toe Game (4x4) Hanging

Tags: c++, algorithm, command-line-interface

I'm working on creating a 4x4 Tic Tac Toe game for a class project. Instead of playing both sides, or using random moves, I've decided to try and implement the Minimax algorithm for making a competitive computer.

I've followed a guide on geeksforgeeks, that shows an implementation of the algorithm. I have followed it to the T (not copy and pasting) to try and understand the algorithm, but whenever it is the computer's turn, it runs the `findBestMove()` function and hangs somewhere inside.

I imagine the problem lies somewhere in the `findBestMove` function, or the `minimax` function that is called within it.

`findBestMove()`

```
Move findBestMove(char board[boardY][boardX])
{
    int bestVal = -1000;
    Move bestMove;
    bestMove.row = -1;
    bestMove.col = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < boardY; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardX; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == ' ')
            {
                board[i][j] = player;

                int moveVal = minimax(board, 0, false);

                board[i][j] = ' ';

                if (moveVal > bestVal)
                {
                    bestMove.row = i;
                    bestMove.col = j;
                    bestVal = moveVal; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The value of the best Move is : %d\n\n", bestVal); 
    return bestMove; 
}
```

Sorry if this block of code is too long.

`minimax()`

```
int minimax(char board[boardY][boardX], int depth, bool isMax) {
    int score = evaluate(board);

    if (score == 10)
        return score;

    if (score == -10)
        return score; 

    if (isMovesLeft(board) == false)
        return 0;

    if (isMax) 
    {
        int best = -1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardY; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardX; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == ' ')
                {
                    board[i][j] == player;

                    best = max(best,
                        minimax(board, depth + 1, !isMax));

                    board[i][j] == ' ';

                }
            }
        }
        return best; 
    }
    else                    // If Mini's move
    {
        int best = 1000;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardY; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardX; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] == ' ') 
                {
                    board[i][j] = opponent;


                    best = min(best, 
                        minimax(board, depth + 1, !isMax));

                    board[i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        return best; 
    }
}
```

The driver code that runs this function is just this:

```
Move move = findBestMove(board);
MakeMove(move, isPlayersTurn);
```

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: The Move x and y values are two very large negative numbers. (-858993460, -858993460)

Comment: How global variables player and opponent is defined? Move struct? evaluate function? isMovesLeft function?

Comment: In question you say "findBestMove() hangs" but in comments you say an invalid move is returned?

Comment: char player = 'x', opponent = 'o', Move { int row, col }, evaluate checks row, column, diagonal victories and returns +10s for them if it's player, -10, if it's opponent, returns 0 if no win condition. 

I say it hangs, because I put a cout at the end of findBestMove() to print the value, and it never reaches it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
board[i][j] == player
```

and also here

```
board[i][j] == ' ';
```

These could cause a stack overflow (or hang, depending on optimisation) because `minimax` will call itself without updating the board.  However if the `else` branch is working correctly this won't occur because the opponent updates will be made.  (Since isMax is set to !isMax on each recursive call.)  It will still make the function quite a lot slower.

Comment: Are you talking about in the `isMax()` part of the `minimax()` function?

Comment: Yes, the "else" branch doesn't have this problem.  More generally it might be a good idea to add some code to `minimax` to dump the board to the console at the start of the function.  That should give you a better idea about what's going on.

Comment: Ah I see, it was a comparison and not assignment. Good catch. Running it again; however, yields the same results. Let me try dumping it to the console.

Okay! So it's infinitely iterating through the `if (isMax)` part of the `minimax()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the board changing?  Are you sure it's not just that the tree you're searching for the 4x4 board is too large?

Comment: The board is changing, I set a breakpoint at the draw, and went through 3 iterations, here's the output: https://imgur.com/a/9iyuAaB

Comment: An empty board with 16 squares might take minute(s) to complete without alpha-beta pruning. Make sure to wait enough time, print something at each iteration in findBestMove function to see if its making progress.

Comment: Do you have an estimate for how many iterations you need to exhaustively search the tree?  (Without memoization, and with no limit on the depth.)  Ignoring the winning condition there are 16! games which is a lot.

Comment: So, to optimize this, I should add alpha-beta pruning. Otherwise, it will run incredibly slow. That makes sense considering a 16! is much larger than 9! 2 * 10^13 vs ~4*10^5. Thank you so much, I appreciate all the help and hand holding.

Comment: @satazero Let me give you some example numbers from another game I was working on, a board with 12 moves were taking 55 seconds with only minimax, then it took ~1 second with alpha-beta pruning. This depends on the game of course.

Comment: @unlut Well, then on to the next task. Thank you so much, your help is invaluable for a novice like me.